# Problem in calculating the surface integral

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

**Problem**

Let S denote the plane surface whose boundary is the triangle with vertices at (1,0,0),(0,1,0), and (0,0,1) , and let **F**(x,y,z) = x**i**+y**j**+z**k**. Let **n** denote the unit normal to S having a nonnegative z-component . Evaluate the surface integral using the vector representation

**r**(u,v)= (u+v)**i**+(u-v)**j**+(1-2u)**k**.

**Attempt**

$\frac{\partial r}{\partial u} = (1,1,-2)$

$\frac{\partial r}{\partial v}=(1,-1,0)$

$\frac{\partial r}{\partial u}×\frac{\partial r}{\partial v}=-2(1,1,1)$

$\iint_T F.n dS= -2\iint_T du dv $

**I am not able to calculate the range of u and v**

i think u will vary from 0 to 1/2 .

**Attempt 2**

$0 \leq y \leq x$ which implies $0 \leq u-v \leq u+v$ which in turn implies $v \leq u$ and $0 \leq v$.So

-2$\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{u} du dv $ = 1/4( change of sign takes place)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand: you have a surface (the triangle, which is merely the part of the plane $\;x+y+z=1\;$ in the first octant), and you have that vector field $\;F\;$.  If you need the surface integral of $\;F\;$ over the surface $\;S\;$ , then what  in the world is that "vector representation" $\;r\;$ about? What you're representing? Are you trying to make a change of variables in the corresponding double (triple) integral, or what? So, what is that $\;r\;$ and, in particular, what is that $\;T\;$ over which you want to integrate?

Comment: @DonAntonio sorry for not being clear.

Comment: @DonAntonio r is the radius vector from the origin to the general point of the surface. We are taking a connected set T in uv plane and the corresponding r traces out a surface in xyz- plane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $\textbf{r} = (u+v) \textbf{i} + (u-v)\textbf{j} + (1-2u)\textbf{k}$ to fill the triangle with vertices $(1,0,0)$, $(0,1,0)$, and $(0,0,1)$ the following restrictions must be placed on the components of $\textbf{r}$

\begin{equation} \tag{1}
0 \leq u+v \leq 1
\end{equation}

\begin{align} \tag{2}
0 \leq u-v \leq 1
\end{align}

\begin{align} \tag{3}
0 \leq 1-2u \leq 1
\end{align}

Subtracting $(3)$ from $(1)$ 
$ \implies 0\leq u+v - (1-2u) \leq 0 \implies 3u-1-v =0 $
$$ v=3u-1 \tag{4}$$

Substitution of $(4)$ into either $(1)$ or $(2)$ shows that $$0 \leq u \leq \frac{1}{2} \tag{5}$$

Notice that $(2)$ implies $v \leq u$. Therefore, for all $u$ that satisfy $(5)$, we have
$$ 3u-1\leq v \leq u  \tag{6} $$

Hence $(5)$ and $(6)$ are the bounds for $u$ and $v$

---

Note: You want $\textbf{n}$ to be in the opposite direction of $-2(1,1,1)$ since this has a negative $z$-component

### Edit

The range for $v$ I originally provided was wrong, but the above ranges should be correct. This can be shown by using the fact that surface integrals are independent under a change of parametric representation. Consider a second parameterization

$$\textbf{r}(x,y) = x \textbf{i} + y \textbf{i} + (1-x-y) \textbf{i} $$

this gives a normal 
$\textbf{n} = \frac{\partial \textbf{r} }{\partial x} \times \frac{\partial \textbf{r} }{\partial y}  = \textbf{i} + \textbf{j} + \textbf{k} $. 
Then 
$$ \iint_S \textbf{F} \cdot \textbf{n} \, dS = \iint_T (x,y,1-x-y) \cdot (1,1,1) dx\, dy = \iint_T dx \, dy = \int_{0}^{1-x} \int_{0}^{1} dx\, dy = \frac{1}{2} $$

Now the parameterization 
$\textbf{r} = (u+v) \textbf{i} + (u-v)\textbf{j} + (1-2u)\textbf{k}$ together with $\textbf{n} = 2\textbf{i} + 2\textbf{j} + 2\textbf{k}$ and the bounds for $u$ and $v$ must give the same answer

$$\iint_S \textbf{F} \cdot \textbf{n} \, dS  = \iint_T (u+v,u-v,1-2u) \cdot (2,2,2) du\, dv = 2 \iint_T du\, dv = 2 \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}} \int_{3u-1}^{u} dv\, du = \frac{1}{2}  $$

Answer (score 0):

Let $\mathbf{a}=\langle 1,1,-2\rangle$ and $\mathbf{b}=\langle 1,-1,0 \rangle.$  Then

$$\mathbf{r}(u,v) = u\mathbf{a}+v\mathbf{b}+\mathbf{k}. $$

If you solve $\mathbf{r}(u,v) = (1,0,0)$ you get $u=1/2$ and $v=1/2$.

If you solve $\mathbf{r}(u,v) = (0,1,0)$ you get $u=1/2$ and $v=-1/2$.

If you solve $\mathbf{r}(u,v) = (0,0,1)$ you get $u=0$ and $v=0$.

So the ranges are $0\leq u \leq 1/2$ and $-1/2\leq v\leq 1/2.$